# Example of an infinite groups, such that all its elements are of finite order and centralizer of any non-central element is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I an in need of:

Example of an infinite groups, such that all its elements are of finite order and centralizer of any non-central elements is finite.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group

Answer (score 2):

consider, $\mathbb{Z_n}[x]$ ,then you get desired redult

Comment: Very nice, but may I ask you to elaborate more? Thanks :)

Comment: This group is an abelian group. Can you give a non-abelian one?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F_1,F_2, \dots$ be copies of some nontrivial finite group $F$. Then $G= \bigoplus\limits_{n \geq 1} F_n$ is an infinite group all of whose elements have finite order. Then:

- $Z(G)= \bigoplus\limits_{ n\geq 1} Z(F_n)$.
- If $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots) \in G$, $C_G(x)= \bigoplus\limits_{ n \geq 1} C_F(x_n)$.

Therefore, any non-central element of $G$ has a finite centralizer iff $Z(G)=G$ ie. $F$ is abelian.